# Using AND condition in LESS language

Tags: css, less

I'm using tags with "border-radius" property.
My website in RTL direction, it's necessary for my explanation.

**When I have 3+ tags:**

- first-child: "border-radius" for right side only.
- others: "border-radius" is disabled.
- last-child: "border-radius" for left side only.

**When I have 2 tag:**

- first-child: "border-radius" for right side only.
- last-child: "border-radius" for left side only.

**When I have 1 tag:**

- first-child AND last-child: "border-radius" for right side and left
  side.

**This works for 2+ tags:**

```
//ANGEL FOR RIGHT TAG
.TagsLabel .TagLabel:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 @border-radius @border-radius 0 !important;
}

//ANGEL FOR LEFT TAG
.TagsLabel .TagLabel:last-child {
    border-radius: @border-radius 0 0 @border-radius !important;
}
```

Can someone help me to fix it for 1 tag also?
Thanks :)

EDIT:
**This is works for me, Thanks anyway!**

```
//ANGEL FOR SINGLE TAG
.TagsLabel .TagLabel:first-child:last-child {
    border-radius: @border-radius !important;
}
```

Comment: Please put an answer in an answer, NOT in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `border-top-left-radius, border-bottom-left-radius, border-top-right-radius, border-bottom-right-radius`
Example here : 
You can invert first-child and last-child if needed.

```
@border-radius:10px;

.TagsLabel .TagLabel {
  background:blue;
  color:#fff;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
}

.TagsLabel .TagLabel:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: @border-radius !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: @border-radius !important;
}

//LEFT ANGEL FOR TAG
.TagsLabel .TagLabel:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: @border-radius !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: @border-radius !important;
}
```

Then when you have only one tag, it will take all the border-radius properties.

Example here : http://codepen.io/arnogues/pen/KzEdWX

Comment: This don't works, Did you know how do I set and condition like: OR / AND to style sheet?

Comment: @IdanHazan, it didn't work because Amaud used the wrong rules. They should have been `border-top-right-radius`, `border-bottom-right-radius`, etc. The general format is correct though.